# Autoprefixer generates the same css code with additional commented sourceMappingURL. How is that useful? Or How do I use it?

Tags: sass, postcss, autoprefixer

I am currently using Sass in my ExpressJS code and have been able to generate a css file using the following command -

```
postcss main.css -u autoprefixer -d dist/
```

The css file **BEFORE** using autoprefixer has the following code :

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2px 2px;
}
```

The css file **AFTER** using autoprefixer has the following code + some commented sourceMappingURL:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2px 2px;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIi4uL21haW4uY3NzIl0sIm5hbWVzIjpbXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiJBQUFBO0VBQ0UsYUFBYTtFQUNiLDhCQUE4QjtBQUNoQyIsImZpbGUiOiJtYWluLmNzcyIsInNvdXJjZXNDb250ZW50IjpbIi5jb250YWluZXIge1xuICBkaXNwbGF5OiBncmlkO1xuICBncmlkLXRlbXBsYXRlLWNvbHVtbnM6IDJweCAycHg7XG59XG4iXX0= */
```

The expected css output (as per [autoprefixer.github.io](http://autoprefixer.github.io/)) should be :

```
.container {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 2px 2px;
  grid-template-columns: 2px 2px;
}
```

My confusion is two-part.

1. Have I messed up the autoprefixer command in anyway? Do I need to correct it somehow to get the expected output?
2. Am I lacking knowledge about how the current output file works ie.,
   (a) Is the generated css file using the autoprefixer command enough?
   (b) Do I need to do something with the sourceMappingURL to get the desired output?

Hope I have explained my question clearly enough. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. At [autoprefixer.github.io](http://autoprefixer.github.io/) there is Browserlist setting below textareas saying "last 4 version". This tells Autoprefixer to add prefixes for older browsers. Most probably you don't have `.browserslistrc` in the root of your project or a `browserslist` key in your `package.json` that would tell autoprefixer which browsers are you targeting, so it takes `defaults`. [browserl.ist](https://browserl.ist/) would help to visualize that (please compare `defaults` with `last 4 version` to see the difference in coverage).
2. Create `browserslist` in the root of your project and explicitly indicate the baseline of browsers you are targeting. [Here](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries) you will find examples on how to construct your queries. Don't worry about source maps - there's nothing you have to do on that side.

Note: Prior to prefix Grid for IE11 (if that's your case), I encourage you to get aquatinted with [CSS Grid in IE: CSS Grid and the New Autoprefixer](https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-css-grid-and-the-new-autoprefixer/)

Comment: Is the sourceMappingURL useful? I used the CLI just to prefix a css file without webpack and I'm wondering if I need to leave the sourceMappingURL comment in there.